# getting an error while trying to publish an artifact

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I'm trying to publish my android library to my private repo but i'm getting this error from the Terminal in android studio :

> Could not publish build-info: Error occurred while requesting version
>   information: Unauthorized

and this is the command :

```
gradlew.bat build artifactoryPublish
```

I used this link to help me set it up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mztbo8WwqRc

It's an official JFrog video

This is what i added to my project gradle :

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
           repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
           username = "${artifactory_user}"
           password = "${artifactory_password}"
           maven = true
       }
   }
   resolve {
       repository {
           repoKey = 'libs-release'
           username = "${artifactory_user}"
           password = "${artifactory_password}"
           maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my gradle.properties where i put the user and pass (got it from artifactory):

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
artifactory_user=${security.getCurrentUsername()}
artifactory_password=${security.getEncryptedPassword()!"*****what_lookes_like_my_encrypted_password****"}
artifactory_contextUrl=http://10.0.1.4:8081/artifactory
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_162
android.enableAapt2=false
```

I'm rather new to the Gradle and Artifactory worlds so any help will do , 
anyone knows what's wrong here ?
Tnx!

Comment: Looks like a user permissions issue. The user you are using lacks permissions to publish the build-info to Artifactory. Try checking the same with a user with admin permissions just to make sure this is indeed the issue

Comment: ok i tried changing to admin , password changed but artifactory_user=${security.getCurrentUsername()}
is still the same , from where does it get the user name  ?

Comment: I changed the user name to artifactory_user="admin" hardcoded , but now the error changed from Unauthorized to Forbidden

Comment: try having the username an password hard coded in gradle just for checking whether this is a permissions issue. If your build succeeds with an admin user, it is likely that the regular user you are using for the build lacks permissions. If you still get the same error with an admin user you probably have another issue

Comment: it worked hardcoded , i guess it didn't get the value passed from gradle.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a permissions issue. The user you are using for publishing should have at least deployment permissions to the target repository.
You can check the user permissions in the Admin > Security > Users > Edit User page (requires admin permissions)

[image]
Or by looking at the effective permissions tab when selecting a repository in the Artifact Repository Browser

[image]